# cvQueryFrame(capture) always returns null

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

Does anyone know why I keep getting null frames? I tried skipping the first five and still null.

```
int _tmain(int argc, char** argv)
{
CvCapture *capture  = cvCaptureFromFile(argv[1]);

int fps = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
IplImage* frame;
cvNamedWindow("video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while(1)
{
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if(!frame)
        break;
    cvShowImage("video", frame);
    char c = cvWaitKey(1000/fps);
    if(c == 33)
        break;
}
cvReleaseCapture( &capture);
cvDestroyWindow( "video" );

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video file must UNCOMPRESSED avi!
So actually I was getting null frames because cvCapture returned a null because my input video file was not uncompressed.

Comment: Even though I didn't nailed the problem, it's obvious that this answer should be the official. Accept it when you can. But always consider up voting the answers that helped you, the ones that lead you to the right track.

Comment: That`s a good point. You helped me trace down the problem to its root. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use your code for test, then it run well with 'xvid' format video.
I think OpenCV 'capture' function maybe process some popular and old format of videos.
Video with format "H264" may be not work.

Answer (score 1):

When `cvCaptureFromFile()` fails it returns `NULL`, and I suspect it is failing:

```
CvCapture *capture  = cvCaptureFromFile(argv[1]);
if (!capture)
{
    // print error, quit application
}
```

It usually fails for one of these reasons: either it can't find the file, or OpenCV doesn't know how to open it. For instance, `.mkv` files are not supported by OpenCV.

Comment: I put in an .wmv file in the same folder as the application(.exe). I tried passing the video to the application using both VC++ under debugging properties and also as a command line argument. For debugging properties I specified Wildlife.wmv and for the command line argument I typed >HelloWorld.exe "Wildlife.wmv".
Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Try with another video type, like .AVI. The result will answer your question.

Comment: The same thing happens even with .avi. Is there a way to determine whether the problem is it can't find the file or that its not supported?

Comment: Sure, try to `fopen()` whatever is in `argv[1]` and check if it succeeds. If it does, you know there's a high probability that OpenCV failed to load the video because of codec related problems.

Comment: I think it failed as well
I tried:
    `FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");`
and file is null.
This is OpenCV 2.2 by the way. I was using 2.4 earlier but I just read thats its buggy.

Comment: If fopen returned NULL it means it wasn't able to find the file. Are you executing your application from within Visual Studio? IF you are, you need to put the video file in the same directory as your source code, and not in the directory of the .exe

Comment: I was trying it both ways. I did it again by copying cube4.avi to the directory of the source file, HelloWorld.cpp, and still nothing. It can`t find it.
I went to Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging 
and in the Command Arguments box I put cube4.avi. Is that correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11395/discussion-between-yahoomania-and-karlphillip)

Comment: Video file must be uncompressed avi,
mine was not.

Comment: Excellent, but printing `argv[1]` should print the filename passed through cmd-line, and your app for some reason was not doing that. Something smells fishy..